# Amazon SP API - Failing to upload feed

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I am working on feeds API(SP API). I successfully finished calling createfeeddocument and in response I got the feeddocumentid and url, using the url I need to upload the feed document. so when I am trying to upload a xml, I get "**The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden..**" . I checked my developer profile and I have all the permissions checked. Not sure what I am missing, can some body please guide as to what this could be referring. I checked the contenttype.... it matches with what I sent in createfeeddocument.

Comment: When a 403 is returned, they usually also return an explaination. You may want to look at the complete raw response. Any update? I am stuck at this step also..... struggling with the 'required' x-amz-content-sha256 header....

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error today and in reviewing the body of the 403 - forbidden response, I determined that the request was failing due to a "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error, which in turn was caused by the content-type of my payload not matching the content type of the signature.

If you look at the "CanonicalRequest" section of the error message, you should find the expected content type.  In my case, the expected type was "application/xml" and I was using "text/xml".